# Mongo Compass crashes after upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04: FATAL gpu_data_manager_impl_private

Tags: mongodb-compass, ubuntu-22.04

After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop to 22.04 Desktop `mongodb-compass` crashes after a fews seconds booting with:

```
mongo compass FATAL gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(894)] The display compositor is frequently crashing
```

It seems like there is an issue with chromium, but I was not able to find a clean fix for this.

Answer (score 3):

I found that running `mongodb-compass --no-sandbox` worked for me on Kubuntu 22.04.1.

I saw this flag on another Electron app issue https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/issues/1025 It looks like a bug in Electron. I believe electron passes this flag to the chromium browser that it uses, however this won't run mongodb compass in a secure sandbox environment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md

Needless to say, it works and I added the flag to my shortcut `/usr/share/applications/mongodb-compass.desktop` which now looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MongoDB Compass
Comment=The MongoDB GUI
GenericName=MongoDB Compass
Exec=mongodb-compass %U --no-sandbox
Icon=mongodb-compass
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was quite simple:

- Remove the old installation: `sudo apt remove mongodb-compass`

Reinstall MongoDB Compass:

- Download the `deb` file from the [official Download page](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass)
- Install with `cd ~/Download` and `sudo apt install ./mongodb-compass_*_amd64.deb` like suggested [here](https://itnixpro.com/install-mongodb-compass-gui-on-ubuntu-22-04/)